# multiple monitor support in application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

What does it mean by multiple monitor support for an application?

Comment: Are you asking in the context of Visual Studio 2010 (one of its hallmark features is multiple monitor support), or in general? Why is your question tagged `visual-studio`?

Comment: i have come across this while going through the vs2010 features and it is the first time i heard multiple monitor support.

Comment: In the case of VS 2010, it means that you can [detach code tabs by dragging them](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/31/multi-monitor-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx). This allows you to put them on a different monitor than the rest of your windows are displayed on. It was probably the single most requested feature for VS 2010. In the previous versions, the tabs were not detachable and it was very difficult to use with more than one monitor. Very common among programmers, you can see more on the screen at a time. I simply can't work without a minimum of 3 monitors anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the old days computers only ever had a single screen attached. Now they often have more than one attached and a desktop that spans those screens.

You need to make sure that your app:

- Maximises to the monitor that it is most closely associated. A badly written app might always maximise a window to the primary monitor.
- Remember which monitor it was displayed on when last run, and restore to that monitor when it starts up again.
- Avoid displaying on a monitor that is no longer available. For example, consider a laptop with an attached screen. If you show the window at coordinates for a screen that has been disconnected (e.g. laptop user on the move) then they won't be able to see it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Windows (and other GUI systems) handle the first one for you for free. You'd have to do a lot of work to make a window maximize to a different screen than it's currently on.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the application.

For some applications it just means that that you could open a very big window.

For others it might mean that you could open two windows, one for each monitor. For example, Lightroom, lets you view a collection of thumbnails on one window and a full-sized image on the other.